# fetch and store data in recycler view from other activity selected list items in android

Tags: android

```
how to store only selected item list data in recycler view from other activity list.
i used this code -- successfully select data but don't know how to add only selected data items in new activity recycler view - 

i used this code snippet ite working fine-

//
```

> https://en.proft.me/2018/03/3/multi-selection-recyclerview/

```
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (ExcercisesSelectedModel.DataBean data : getList()) {
                if (selectedIds.contains(data.getId()))
                    stringBuilder.append("\n").append(data.getName());
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
public interface OnClickAction {
        public void onClickAction();
    }
```

to

```
public interface OnClickAction {
        public void onClickAction(Item item);
    }
```

In adapter class, on item click

```
receiver.onClickAction(item);
```

In Activity class

```
private List<Item> selectedItem = new ArrayList()

public void onClickAction(Item item) {
        selectedItem.add(item);
}
```

Now use this selected item list in new activity.

Edit: Don't forget to use or rename the interface to Callback, something along the lines of ActivityCallback or OnClickCallback.

This is for the sake of naming conventions.

Comment: this is not about select item this is about to post and store selected data on new activity recycler view

Answer (score 0):

A simple flag `isSelected` in parent list will save your day.

So whenever user select/unselect the item just change the value of `isSelected` flag to `true` or `false`. 
Now you have a final list from which you can easily identify selected items, simple store in separated list named `selectedItemList`.

At last use the `selectedItemList` and fill your `Recycleview`. Hope it make sense.

Comment: If you understand the logic then start developing and if you stuck anywhere then come back. hav a good code.